# Insert Webpages into Div instead of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here's the entire code for my loop.html file.  It first pulls the list of urls from a separate XML file that is in the same directory and then loops through them, given specified time.  The time element is the amount it will wait until it cycles to the next page.  What I want to do is to use DIV to cycle through the URLs, since iframe is not supported in all the browsers and does not display some of the content when I run the html script.  The thing I am not sure about is what to do with the "dashboard.url"--when i want to use a div?

I found this piece of code from a different site--that when you replace the frams['theDisplay'] line with, it sets the div to a webpage--but I want to have something like this, using the dashboard.url

```
$("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://latimes.com" />');
```

I am sorry if this is a really long question, and if you get frustrated.  I am just trying to learn as I go.  Thank you!

Example of list.xml format:

```
<list>
<url>
<link>http:latimes.com</link>
<time>2</time>
</url>
<url>
<link>http:stackoverflow.com</link>
<time>4</time>
</url>
</list>
```

Entire HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--Created by Megan Chiu  - 30 June 2013-->
<html>

<!-- CSS -->
<style type="text/css">
displayArea {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%
    width: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

object {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}       
</style>  

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
                 overflow: hidden; }
    iframe { border: none; }

</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var Dash = {
        nextIndex: 0,
        dashboards: [],

        loadXML: function() {
            $.ajax( {
                type: "GET",
                url: "list.xml", 
                dataType: "xml",
                success: Dash.renderXML
            });
        },

        renderXML: function(xml) {

            $(xml).find("url").each(function() {
                var _link = $(this).find('link').text();
                var _time  = $(this).find('time').text();
                Dash.dashboards.push({url:_link, time:_time});
            }); 

            Dash.display();

            },

        display: function()
        {
            var dashboard = Dash.dashboards[Dash.nextIndex];    
            frames['theDisplay'].location.href = dashboard.url;
            Dash.nextIndex = (Dash.nextIndex + 1) % Dash.dashboards.length;
            setTimeout(Dash.display, dashboard.time * 1000);
        }    
    };
    window.onload = Dash.loadXML;
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<iframe id="theDisplay" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</html>
```

Comment: There are no browsers worth worrying about that don't support iframes.

Comment: That's somewhat subjective, but there are no browsers which support loading HTML documents via `<object>` that don't have better support for loading via `<iframe>`.

Comment: You could try `$("#theDisplay").load(dashboard.url)`, but it probably won't work because of the AJAX same-origin policy. To get around this, you'll need to run a proxy server.

Comment: @Quentin  

I do not have to use <object>.  I just want to be able to use <div> instead of <iframe> to loop through the URL pages.  I know it is possible--but I just do not know what the code is.

Comment: @Barmar thank you! I already tried this and it didn't work--do you know of any other ways around this?

Comment: The basic problem is that web sites are not generally designed so they can be embedded in a DIV. They have their own `<head>` and `<body>` sections, you can't nest these in a DIV. Iframes are designed specifically to allow embedding, by putting each in its own sandbox.

Comment: BTW, the URLs in your XML are no good, they're missing `//` before the server name.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks.  I know the URLs are no good, it's just that for the actual URLs that I am using--when I run Chrome, there is some information (pics) that do not show up, but when running IE, the pictures do show up, and I suspect this is because of using iframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div id="content1"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("content1").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="header.php" ></object>';
alert('Load_Ok');
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You cannot load content from another website just with pure JavaScript. Period.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

So what you can do? You can make a web request from your server and get Http response from remote server and put them into div element.

```
<div><%=(new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://www.stackoverflow.com")%></div>
```

But one of biggest problem is that, since you will download all styles and scripts from remote website then your page probably will not look good. Not even human readable. And if you will keep hitting from same IP to those servers you will may blocked by them.

Good luck.

Comment: If I replace:

frames['theDisplay'].location.href = dashboard.url;

with:

$("#theDisplay").html('<object data="http://latimes.com" />');

This works in the div! Given that you write <div id="theDisplay"></div> instead of the <iframe></iframe>.  What I want to do is use the dashboard.url--which holds the current url to be looped through.

Comment: I -1'd this answer because that's not entirely true.  You can do this in your source: <script src="http://anotherwebsite.com/content.js"></script> Then that file, content.js, could set a javascript variable that is the content you want (perhaps as html or a jQuery object).  Then simply display it on your page.

Comment: @Magmatic How you planning to place you own script on remote website? And if you think your comment is an answer, place it as answer not as comment.

Comment: Perhaps your site is http://yourwebsite.com, and you want to make a secure AJAX connection to httpS://yourwebsite.com to display the user's password or something using pure Javascript.  Technically this is a different website because it has a different protocol, so the Same Origin Policy would forbid it, but you can still do it the way I described.  I just don't want people to think that "you cannot load content from another website just with pure JavaScript. Period. ", because there are ways around it.

Comment: "another website" means "another website" not yours. Look at the question, OP is asking about websites are not own by him.